# Is there a fast way, to create a vector with 1 and x * 0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

is there a fast way, to create a vector with 1 and x * 0 in python?

I would like to have something like

```
a = [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,...,0]
b = [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,...,0]
```

I tried it with list but see yourself :(

```
lst = [1, n*[0]]
lst = np.array(lst)
print(lst)
==> [1 list([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])]
```

Comment: Try to avoid naming your list `list`, by the way, because it will override the built-in name `list`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For optimal performance, see the AMC's `numpy` answer below.

---

Use [`unpacking`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) by simply adding an asterisk to your code: `[1, *n*[0]]` instead of `[1, n*[0]]`:

```
>>> arr = np.array([1, *n*[0]])
```

---

```
array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Answer (score 8):

A proper NumPy solution:

```py
import numpy as np

n = 10
arr = np.zeros(shape=n + 1, dtype=np.int64)
arr[0] = 1
```

Results in: `[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]`

---

#### Quick benchmarks

Here are the functions we're going to compare:

```py
def func_1(n):
    return np.array([1, *n*[0]])

def func_2(n):
    arr = np.zeros(shape=n + 1, dtype=np.int64)
    arr[0] = 1
    return arr

def func_3(n):
    return np.array([1] + n * [0])

def func_4(n):
    return np.array([1] + [0 for _ in range(n)])

def func_5(n):
    return np.array([1].extend((0 for _ in range(n))))

def func_6(n):
    return np.array([1].extend([0 for _ in range(n)]))

def func_7(n):
    arr = [0 for _ in range(n)]
    arr[0] = 1
    return np.array(arr)
```

Results of `timeit` for `arr_size = 100000000`:

- `%timeit func_1(arr_size)`

  > 1 loop, best of 3: 7.3 s per loop
- `%timeit func_2(arr_size)`

  > 10 loops, best of 3: 177 ms per loop
- `%timeit func_3(arr_size)`

  > 1 loop, best of 3: 7.26 s per loop
- `%timeit func_4(arr_size)`

  > 1 loop, best of 3: 11.4 s per loop
- `%timeit func_5(arr_size)`

  > 1 loop, best of 3: 6.3 s per loop
- `%timeit func_6(arr_size)`

  > 1 loop, best of 3: 4.95 s per loop
- `%timeit func_7(arr_size)`

  > 1 loop, best of 3: 10.6 s per loop

Answer (score 0):

There is another NumPy solution with only slightly worse performance than the one posted by @AMC, but with the convenience that it is a single expression and doesn't need to be wrapped in a function to be used inline:

```py
>>> n = 10
>>> np.eye(1, n + 1, 0, dtype=int)[0]
array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

It's also easy to create other one-hot vectors of the same length by changing the third argument:

```py
>> np.eye(1, n + 1, 4, dtype=int)[0]
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Here's how the performance compares to @AMC's `func_2` above (same `arr_size = 100000000`):

```py
def func_8(n, k=0):
    return np.eye(1, n + 1, k, dtype=int)[0]
```

```py
>>> %timeit func_2(arr_size)
16.4 µs ± 111 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
>>> %timeit func_8(arr_size)
19 µs ± 113 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```